# Rails assets not loaded in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, assets

i'm facing to a problem. WHen I run my app in development mode, always run well but when I run it in production mode, assets are not loaded, see the source code of the head page in production :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html data-no-turbolink="true">

  <head>
    <title>
      Se connecter - Tick{Master}
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/application-58c87518596f09b30d0db6ec750f3465.css" />
    <script src="/assets/application-cd97d1e5bb179f9230219a04392157bd.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/chartkick-4936d4dfcc035e087fb36d935871a2b4.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui.min-e79f6566871719060387f672b09e45e1.js"></script>
    <meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token" />
<meta name="csrf-token" content="wem26VXIMznqlZhlDaFJP8xaikG0AXO6EyiQ4XB0sgpdO8ckH3yn1VE+2jeH2zfNfILre4rpcQAWOrLmE9Ci6A==" />
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
    <meta content="IE=edge,chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/assets/favicon-b3a5a16fe1e9484cba7bf759cfd55098.ico" />
  </head>
```

and here in development mode :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html data-no-turbolink="true">

  <head>
    <title>
      Se connecter - Tick{Master}
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/application-f60e2f4af6cc403e56e3cc4af237f418.css?body=1" />
    <script src="/assets/jquery-4075e3b7b3964707c653f61b66f46dec.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/affix-47fdb29aafe4a822de223cafa771308d.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/alert-b393e4a3c7100b53fff3a72ca2563886.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/button-a2a5158d99c02fae2b04bc27d371a4b6.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/carousel-ab9494d16078563fa942fa36f51606ce.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/collapse-2388931b28922c87b9d067e091918f79.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/dropdown-a2d3f333085e0bc153c5d488f9c25beb.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/tab-b0e0085ddbe601df70783e3b00a44a66.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/transition-9486a84e28a255d97b73f24291099503.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/scrollspy-3f18290693c0ab56cf81606aa54c14af.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/modal-8d7b95e2d768d4ece3faa24139930b0b.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/tooltip-f84ca665f20377fe06f80929f5951ab6.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/popover-05732afcfe8b7487e51d82ce3f8a0c14.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-sprockets-8424ed52c356487c7b529345da7d256c.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/highcharts-5a025aa6728c7ccebe3af43a4db9e4ea.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/chartkick-5a958c4cd62954f0cde5ee45e6dc6d34.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/ckeditor/init-ebc09218fc53d6f3d58a47d266e36e1d.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/ckeditor/ckeditor-14272f4a8f42f66c92aeacabce50c014.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs-f9f4ae336c0d19804775e0e2c8749423.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/agencies-0bc27e2168727cafa1252f703137df60.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/application-4e11c171777093c5dbbc217515dd8224.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-slider-da831c089b66bfa5bbeb8b49d41d1907.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/categories-0bc27e2168727cafa1252f703137df60.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/ckeditor/config-eae0b86dbfcb323917018a90db40a0a0.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/ckeditor/configm-8fa2c3e7b9bd535a525fc1fc7bbf8ee0.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/ckeditor/plugins/notification/lang/cs-35843edb8844d6758bc43120897d2b91.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/ckeditor/plugins/notification/lang/da-73b51dffb7cd6277297c038c331e34f2.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/ckeditor/plugins/notification/lang/de-ch-7d771d043115cbd3e34e7e6a2ad855ae.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/ckeditor/plugins/notification/lang/de-8e0ecde7cbc138635d7161312c02ea11.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/ckeditor/plugins/notification/lang/en-a9d8727623db97cbfd8ecbe7ce4dc490.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/ckeditor/plugins/notification/lang/eo-5e7a3e96d60e97b10f9642fac7621333.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/ckeditor/plugins/notification/lang/eu-35cd319df52d87985afc1c90fbcf3cfd.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/ckeditor/plugins/notification/lang/fr-acfe2024ebe8ac0a2ce393f7191f81cb.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/ckeditor/plugins/notification/lang/gl-63c5f69a7bf1da986296ae07c425658f.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/ckeditor/plugins/notification/lang/id-9e62b221e165194be044359199315ca1.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/ckeditor/plugins/notification/lang/it-feed39f5d127b150c84c71dda89f40b2.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/ckeditor/plugins/notification/lang/km-1087fc8ec5a6ab84f87a2592e896c05b.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/ckeditor/plugins/notification/lang/ko-abbaf475666179bc18d042ccaab433f0.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/ckeditor/plugins/notification/lang/ku-1b740745b2aca9afda23d64bf60a0adf.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/ckeditor/plugins/notification/lang/nb-89face14fd7b8560cbe0da2fa9db2983.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/ckeditor/plugins/notification/lang/nl-c88c3d7c24e6f5394a06aa02a745640b.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/ckeditor/plugins/notification/lang/pl-f2af2b5df712e0d5ee684f1b1473a6ae.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/ckeditor/plugins/notification/lang/pt-br-c6ad971ffe318b67b81d37f5ff12a6c4.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/ckeditor/plugins/notification/lang/pt-46fe4b8397e133a428dfffdde83bb941.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/ckeditor/plugins/notification/lang/ru-6900c82f0d407c87f6233c0583d1bce7.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/ckeditor/plugins/notification/lang/sv-21da89fe5c0a548ff0928b14a594d448.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/ckeditor/plugins/notification/lang/tr-9e8670eddc71e0ee55fea933f783e90b.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/ckeditor/plugins/notification/lang/ug-99d4085b58533705ded3c469b232d6cb.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/ckeditor/plugins/notification/lang/uk-4c973cc12be3df0fdfe8fea666a591b2.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/ckeditor/plugins/notification/lang/zh-cn-e827c9dbd4cd64d9f05d0f475460c466.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/ckeditor/plugins/notification/lang/zh-7db9dc0eea18212b85d43f89693f1dad.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/ckeditor/plugins/notification/plugin-56df4a55dabf23e20f207a03b454e7e1.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/ckeditor/plugins/wordcount/lang/ar-9fb6d0738a3daa5ab12c7e9a227e7b15.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/ckeditor/plugins/wordcount/lang/ca-ca4c6f9dfd68de2b175359f9cebeb046.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/ckeditor/plugins/wordcount/lang/da-608f9e749f90ebd01ed6565401536993.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/ckeditor/plugins/wordcount/lang/de-1543f26f4b83f632322c3f6c50ae43ef.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/ckeditor/plugins/wordcount/lang/el-a9ae3cadfda522eb6192205e68ab294c.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/ckeditor/plugins/wordcount/lang/en-bf0f18bd7920f0a705f08e768e53efb5.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/ckeditor/plugins/wordcount/lang/es-9cc34d82b724d7d0358d5072e9b34dd2.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/ckeditor/plugins/wordcount/lang/fi-05a9c0d4e6b09944b5d899b556b86ada.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/ckeditor/plugins/wordcount/lang/fr-4ae4717bb8310f0eb3fd943116a73451.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/ckeditor/plugins/wordcount/lang/he-01efbfda508c1a4988e5caec82d0ba3b.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/ckeditor/plugins/wordcount/lang/hr-0836be2fc736bc011b5193dd73119823.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/ckeditor/plugins/wordcount/lang/it-d4ab9841c3da9f46699976b93a32f706.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/ckeditor/plugins/wordcount/lang/jp-a0091b6ca1a3fc1afd368fd5e0d1b9e8.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/ckeditor/plugins/wordcount/lang/nl-ff900411ee2f004f3ccc54e34f86f274.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/ckeditor/plugins/wordcount/lang/no-24d86423e8e69521438b952f235a46b7.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/ckeditor/plugins/wordcount/lang/pl-db55b30c77d9cf1ad2b7cb1fccc4e7d7.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/ckeditor/plugins/wordcount/lang/pt-br-4abcb5fd52cf73f675bc06744d9fdf74.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/ckeditor/plugins/wordcount/lang/pt-8d221aefa4afcadb502c882a2b7e6042.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/ckeditor/plugins/wordcount/lang/ru-7219f804506056fa7c219ace9c8ef67c.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/ckeditor/plugins/wordcount/lang/sv-083d4c2e1bc385d353739e6cddc4032f.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/ckeditor/plugins/wordcount/lang/tr-bca64f04572a257f2fc61f1ae39d8aa5.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/ckeditor/plugins/wordcount/lang/zh-cn-b2bc9187c7d606ee18632a7a9fcb0cda.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/ckeditor/plugins/wordcount/plugin-d5d4e3f76225eef5196db3672b207787.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/detentor_types-0bc27e2168727cafa1252f703137df60.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/fields_sellers-0bc27e2168727cafa1252f703137df60.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/fixedheadertable-c73eddcf4550a5bb7c65388519c5ac28.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/incidents-5fbc77d42db3e44b3d43dc43f86022f7.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui.min-5d90b08454cc699eb8e1bc94de9c7962.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.tablesorter.min-1d78abce8f27094ff5d60e0efdae6ad7.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.min-11823e766ac5b5e620666447309523bf.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/materials-0bc27e2168727cafa1252f703137df60.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/nprogress-2fdff496bfac3f217d74c009dc54d771.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/pages-0bc27e2168727cafa1252f703137df60.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/pingAgenciesWorker-b3a51add05415564e766b8593f89eba7.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/procedures-798fe5b55c5655b004f8a10d74a38331.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/responses-0bc27e2168727cafa1252f703137df60.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/scaffold-0bc27e2168727cafa1252f703137df60.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/sellers-0bc27e2168727cafa1252f703137df60.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/sessions-0bc27e2168727cafa1252f703137df60.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/sous_categories-0bc27e2168727cafa1252f703137df60.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/specs_materials-0bc27e2168727cafa1252f703137df60.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/specs_types_materials-0bc27e2168727cafa1252f703137df60.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/teches-0bc27e2168727cafa1252f703137df60.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/type_materials-0bc27e2168727cafa1252f703137df60.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/updates-0bc27e2168727cafa1252f703137df60.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/users-0bc27e2168727cafa1252f703137df60.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/widgets/widget-alignChar-20f21dcad0b3e7bdaa7d65f347ca5c06.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/widgets/widget-build-table-9980915e694f6473234d002a38eae2f6.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/widgets/widget-chart-f5c41018d011e80be18035a696162cee.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/widgets/widget-columnSelector-902e6789eb11935d092f950e63e971ac.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/widgets/widget-columns-93fb24903c9a016f29454f9d7e5ea822.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/widgets/widget-cssStickyHeaders-c52e4f03457c04871e637d8ce7f9ee17.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/widgets/widget-editable-668042e1978bed370ff9038bb32d5206.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/widgets/widget-filter-formatter-html5-db379e8c3c7e5372c207a46143518afe.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/widgets/widget-filter-formatter-jui-d346f9b05e0dd035da6c6acae127745f.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/widgets/widget-filter-formatter-select2-1458be5e4fbbd4366ca1f6ef2be87f14.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/widgets/widget-filter-type-insideRange-3b164e8c429b44b376b541e4bbcdb03f.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/widgets/widget-filter-17549c0839926560622416167a40d7ac.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/widgets/widget-formatter-0579addee85b8173a958aac034ab0b1e.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/widgets/widget-grouping-25b4b58f76174db72af39b66c3022335.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/widgets/widget-headerTitles-c24fbf7fb27103f42c9fa990d263b1cb.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/widgets/widget-lazyload-f65c879eaefc138d5c7695947f5c648e.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/widgets/widget-math-12530ee8ab16797115777282aa911c8f.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/widgets/widget-output-0c2c0cce7d1115ec9ccc5891fb3de5a6.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/widgets/widget-pager-b282f3c8ae3af25ada37287241b9f9d0.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/widgets/widget-print-0d4831613f57f9534cbca6826343881a.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/widgets/widget-reflow-7e8822e75b3d403d63178bc702e27982.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/widgets/widget-repeatheaders-56c76027e9678677afbbe95028cf5eac.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/widgets/widget-resizable-0ff2c94ce4a766de21935a2867e3d018.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/widgets/widget-saveSort-4f6d025239734be02182c0ed01502c69.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/widgets/widget-scroller-e7738cb4c732c10a62a7a9f61632a7d8.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/widgets/widget-sort2Hash-c70d10a28427f795373ea8c239134e36.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/widgets/widget-sortTbodies-cc3e898271fc28a4e19418be192ca3e0.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/widgets/widget-staticRow-29f47c6645fea83baccddaa39963db55.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/widgets/widget-stickyHeaders-178596f1c42e3eb08d6f479e935537d0.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/widgets/widget-storage-8daa03484a290dcefc8590c2c746c12f.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/widgets/widget-toggle-bdaad06c070541829e76ea8fe0f69835.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/widgets/widget-uitheme-08d38b76df75bcf6c5dc48744cb0b8ab.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/widgets/widget-view-b22d40cfa799ebe7e01f153b64c724b0.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui.min-5d90b08454cc699eb8e1bc94de9c7962.js?body=1"></script>
    <meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token" />
<meta name="csrf-token" content="7UT0X7nMOkeNiQ8dAIoDHYXb3lvXfZfWassGFB6vlOr/Gqt7EFVWs4x93YlX1petedBs6vt9w6qt9joywf3C0Q==" />
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
    <meta content="IE=edge,chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/assets/favicon-4cc1b862a3189189a00864097b80d09a.ico" />
  </head>
```

Here production.rb file :

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.eager_load = true
  config.serve_static_files = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: '10.134.2.250' }
  config.assets.compile = true
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.serve_static_files = true
  config.log_level = :debug
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end
```

and development.rb file :

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = false
  config.eager_load = false
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.log_level = :debug
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load
  config.assets.debug = true
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: '192.168.10.49:3000' }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.serve_static_files = true
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true
end
```

Sorry for too much code and for my poor English... And Thank you !

**EDIT :**  Before to have this bug on asset production, I updated Sprockets and compass-rails, see that diff of Gemfile.lock :

```
GIT
   - remote: git://github.com/Compass/compass-rails.git
   - revision: d600de4a6c5870613aac63f32491da4771a3c982
   + remote: https://github.com/Compass/compass-rails.git
   + revision: 86afb2c45ae329b3720be102c549612703e16402
   branch: master
   specs:
     - compass-rails (2.0.5)
     + compass-rails (3.0.2)
       compass (~> 1.0.0)
       sass-rails (< 5.1)
       - sprockets (< 2.13)
       + sprockets (< 4.0)

 GIT
   - remote: git://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor.git
   + remote: https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor.git
   revision: 189d3c2bc9ec177947aec6932da03eb5a03f6879
   specs:
     ckeditor (4.2.0)
... ...
@@ -91,7 +91,7 @@ GEM
       railties (>= 3.0)
       sass-rails (>= 3.2)
     chronic (0.10.2)
     - chunky_png (1.3.4)
     + chunky_png (1.3.6)
     climate_control (0.0.3)
       activesupport (>= 3.0)
     cocaine (0.5.7)
```

So I had nothing else changed and this bug appears come from nowhere ... And now, I have functions JS that worked very well before that and now does not work ... Even if i use `config.assets.debug = true` or false ... I can saw in developer tool mode Chromium that :

```
Calling Element.createShadowRoot() for an element which already hosts a shadow root is deprecated. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/4668884095336448 for more details.
VM8885:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeAttribute' of null(anonymous function) @ VM8885:5(anonymous function) @ VM8885:20
application-cd97d1e….js?body=1:12828 Uncaught Error: Highcharts error #16: www.highcharts.com/errors/16error @ application-cd97d1e….js?body=1:12828(anonymous function) @ application-cd97d1e….js?body=1:12837(anonymous function) @ application-cd97d1e….js?body=1:12729(anonymous function) @ application-cd97d1e….js?body=1:12731
init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'langEntries' of nullCKEDITOR.plugins.setLang @ init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246(anonymous function) @ cs-35843ed….js?body=1:6
init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'langEntries' of nullCKEDITOR.plugins.setLang @ init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246(anonymous function) @ da-73b51df….js?body=1:6
init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'langEntries' of nullCKEDITOR.plugins.setLang @ init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246(anonymous function) @ de-ch-7d771d0….js?body=1:6
init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'langEntries' of nullCKEDITOR.plugins.setLang @ init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246(anonymous function) @ de-8e0ecde….js?body=1:6
init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'langEntries' of nullCKEDITOR.plugins.setLang @ init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246(anonymous function) @ en-a9d8727….js?body=1:6
init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'langEntries' of nullCKEDITOR.plugins.setLang @ init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246(anonymous function) @ eo-5e7a3e9….js?body=1:6
init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'langEntries' of nullCKEDITOR.plugins.setLang @ init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246(anonymous function) @ eu-35cd319….js?body=1:6
init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'langEntries' of nullCKEDITOR.plugins.setLang @ init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246(anonymous function) @ fr-acfe202….js?body=1:6
init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'langEntries' of nullCKEDITOR.plugins.setLang @ init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246(anonymous function) @ gl-63c5f69….js?body=1:6
init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'langEntries' of nullCKEDITOR.plugins.setLang @ init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246(anonymous function) @ id-9e62b22….js?body=1:6
init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'langEntries' of nullCKEDITOR.plugins.setLang @ init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246(anonymous function) @ it-feed39f….js?body=1:6
init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'langEntries' of nullCKEDITOR.plugins.setLang @ init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246(anonymous function) @ km-1087fc8….js?body=1:6
init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'langEntries' of nullCKEDITOR.plugins.setLang @ init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246(anonymous function) @ ko-abbaf47….js?body=1:6
init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'langEntries' of nullCKEDITOR.plugins.setLang @ init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246(anonymous function) @ ku-1b74074….js?body=1:6
init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'langEntries' of nullCKEDITOR.plugins.setLang @ init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246(anonymous function) @ nb-89face1….js?body=1:6
init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'langEntries' of nullCKEDITOR.plugins.setLang @ init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246(anonymous function) @ nl-c88c3d7….js?body=1:6
init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'langEntries' of nullCKEDITOR.plugins.setLang @ init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246(anonymous function) @ pl-f2af2b5….js?body=1:6
init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'langEntries' of nullCKEDITOR.plugins.setLang @ init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246(anonymous function) @ pt-br-c6ad971….js?body=1:6
init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'langEntries' of nullCKEDITOR.plugins.setLang @ init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246(anonymous function) @ pt-46fe4b8….js?body=1:6
init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'langEntries' of nullCKEDITOR.plugins.setLang @ init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246(anonymous function) @ ru-6900c82….js?body=1:6
init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'langEntries' of nullCKEDITOR.plugins.setLang @ init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246(anonymous function) @ sv-21da89f….js?body=1:6
init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'langEntries' of nullCKEDITOR.plugins.setLang @ init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246(anonymous function) @ tr-9e8670e….js?body=1:6
init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'langEntries' of nullCKEDITOR.plugins.setLang @ init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246(anonymous function) @ ug-99d4085….js?body=1:6
init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'langEntries' of nullCKEDITOR.plugins.setLang @ init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246(anonymous function) @ uk-4c973cc….js?body=1:6
init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'langEntries' of nullCKEDITOR.plugins.setLang @ init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246(anonymous function) @ zh-cn-e827c9d….js?body=1:6
init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'langEntries' of nullCKEDITOR.plugins.setLang @ init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246(anonymous function) @ zh-7db9dc0….js?body=1:6
init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'langEntries' of nullCKEDITOR.plugins.setLang @ init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246(anonymous function) @ ar-9fb6d07….js?body=1:3
init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'langEntries' of nullCKEDITOR.plugins.setLang @ init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246(anonymous function) @ ca-ca4c6f9….js?body=1:6
init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'langEntries' of nullCKEDITOR.plugins.setLang @ init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246(anonymous function) @ da-608f9e7….js?body=1:6
init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'langEntries' of nullCKEDITOR.plugins.setLang @ init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246(anonymous function) @ de-1543f26….js?body=1:6
init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'langEntries' of nullCKEDITOR.plugins.setLang @ init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246(anonymous function) @ el-a9ae3ca….js?body=1:6
init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'langEntries' of nullCKEDITOR.plugins.setLang @ init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246(anonymous function) @ en-bf0f18b….js?body=1:6
init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'langEntries' of nullCKEDITOR.plugins.setLang @ init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246(anonymous function) @ es-9cc34d8….js?body=1:6
init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'langEntries' of nullCKEDITOR.plugins.setLang @ init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246(anonymous function) @ fi-05a9c0d….js?body=1:7
init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'langEntries' of nullCKEDITOR.plugins.setLang @ init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246(anonymous function) @ fr-4ae4717….js?body=1:3
init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'langEntries' of nullCKEDITOR.plugins.setLang @ init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246(anonymous function) @ he-01efbfd….js?body=1:6
init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'langEntries' of nullCKEDITOR.plugins.setLang @ init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246(anonymous function) @ hr-0836be2….js?body=1:6
init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'langEntries' of nullCKEDITOR.plugins.setLang @ init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246(anonymous function) @ it-d4ab984….js?body=1:7
init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'langEntries' of nullCKEDITOR.plugins.setLang @ init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246(anonymous function) @ jp-a0091b6….js?body=1:6
init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'langEntries' of nullCKEDITOR.plugins.setLang @ init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246(anonymous function) @ nl-ff90041….js?body=1:6
init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'langEntries' of nullCKEDITOR.plugins.setLang @ init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246(anonymous function) @ no-24d8642….js?body=1:2
init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'langEntries' of nullCKEDITOR.plugins.setLang @ init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246(anonymous function) @ pl-db55b30….js?body=1:6
init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'langEntries' of nullCKEDITOR.plugins.setLang @ init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246(anonymous function) @ pt-br-4abcb5f….js?body=1:6
init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'langEntries' of nullCKEDITOR.plugins.setLang @ init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246(anonymous function) @ pt-8d221ae….js?body=1:1
init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'langEntries' of nullCKEDITOR.plugins.setLang @ init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246(anonymous function) @ ru-7219f80….js?body=1:6
init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'langEntries' of nullCKEDITOR.plugins.setLang @ init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246(anonymous function) @ sv-083d4c2….js?body=1:6
init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'langEntries' of nullCKEDITOR.plugins.setLang @ init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246(anonymous function) @ tr-bca64f0….js?body=1:6
init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'langEntries' of nullCKEDITOR.plugins.setLang @ init-77b1ac4….js?body=1:246(anonymous function) @ zh-cn-b2bc918….js?body=1:6
1:2211 Uncaught TypeError: Notification.requestPermission is not a function(anonymous function) @ 1:2211
measureIt.js:120 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined(anonymous function) @ measureIt.js:120
```

Comment: did you `precompile` assets in production?

Answer (score 1):

```
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

just use this command to precompile your assets into production env. :)

Comment: when I do that (with --trace) it fail on error : `Sass::SyntaxError: Undefined variable: "$background-navbar-connected-jour".
  (in /home/jeremy/TickMasterV2/app/assets/stylesheets/arrow_up_page.scss:15)`

Comment: I confirm that the problem is with *.css on config.assets.precompile. You need to be more specific, otherwise it will try to compile sass partials too.

Comment: I modified that and it precompile well but there are yet a bug with the css/js that I don't have in development mode oO

Comment: does you try precompile into your development?

Comment: I think I found the solution and I know why it bug for that .... I just put in production.rb that line : `config.assets.debug = true` and it works ... But I don't know why ... :/ Can you explain this ? I found that solution by copy the lines of development.rb file one-by-one and luckily it works ...

Comment: config.assets.debug = true: assets are served individually, organized just as you see them in development. Preprocessed languages like SASS or CoffeeScript will still show up as their target languages (i.e., CSS and JS, respectively).

Comment: Okey so, why it does not works wthout `config.assets.debug = true` ??

Comment: Please refer my last comment you will got reason, Why not working

Comment: I'm sorry I wanted to write : "Why it does not workds without `config.assets.debug = false` It works well when assets files are served individually but not when assets are compiled, why ?

Comment: config.assets.debug = false: assets are bundled into files like application.css and application.js. Error stack traces will likely not have the correct line number any more and it is harder to map those back to your original code.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand why it don't works with `config.assets.debug = false`

Comment: i will comment link if i got any live ex whom explain some core about this diff. :)

Comment: Thank you but I have an another bug, I edit my post to explain.

Comment: I think that the other bug was caused by the update of sprockets-rails and compass-rails, see my edited post please.

Answer (score 0):

I think that assets are successfully loaded, in production environment all assets are concatenated in application.js and application.css in your case

```
 <script src="/assets/application-cd97d1e5bb179f9230219a04392157bd.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/application-58c87518596f09b30d0db6ec750f3465.css" />
```

run `rake assets:precompile` to migrate your changes to these files (maybe you need to delete the folder `public/assets/` and precompile again)